# Convert hours to minutes, SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, time

How can I find the difference between this, for example, 1700 hours and 1020 hours.

This time is in varchar type. I want to find the exact time difference between this (24 hour format).

Need:

I want to get 1800 - 1715 = 45 mins. How to achieve this?

**Answer**

```
 select DATEDIFF(mi, convert(datetime,LEFT('1020',2) + ':' + RIGHT('1020',2),8), 
 convert(datetime,LEFT('1700',2) + ':' + RIGHT('1700',2),8))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will return you 400 minutes, then you can calculate hours and minutes like '6 hrs 40 minutes'.

```
select DATEDIFF(mi, convert(datetime, '10:20'),  convert(datetime, '17:00'))
```

Comment: simply insert a colon after two digits.